# Error: ! Extra \else

Tags: errors, layout

I'm not a frequent user of Latex and I keep getting the following error when I try to compile my main tex file:

```
! Extra \else.
\@include ...ediate \closeout \@partaux \fi \else
\deadcycles \z@ \@nameuse ...
l.5 \include{01_layout}
```

I want to include my layout file, but it seems like there's something wrong with it! The main file starts the following way:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article} 
\include{01_layout} 
...
```

The layout file is quite long, but since I don't know where the error might come from I think including the whole code is reasonable:

```
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage[left=40mm,right=20mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{setspace}                                            
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,acronym=true,toc=true]{glossaries}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}

\usepackage{siunitx} 
  \sisetup{
        detect-mode,
        input-symbols = {()},
        input-open-uncertainty  = ,
        input-close-uncertainty = ,
        tight-spacing           = true,
        group-digits            = false
        }
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}   
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} 
\usepackage{threeparttablex} 
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} 
\newcommand{\bftab}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}  
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{enumitem}   


\usepackage{float}      
\usepackage{subfiles}  

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}   
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{epstopdf}                           
\definecolor{MidnightBlue}{rgb}{0.1, 0.1, 0.44}
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.8}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}   
\usepackage{mathrsfs}                          
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{\symbolslistname} 
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}
\makeindex

\glossarystyle{long}


\makeglossaries


\fancypagestyle{plain}{               
\fancyhf{}                           
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}               
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}    
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}    
}
\pagestyle{fancy}                               
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}                                      
\fancyhead[L]{\sc \leftmark}                  
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}                         
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}            
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}             

\setlength{\parskip}{1.5ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{2mm}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\refname{Literaturverzeichnis}}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{satz}{Satz}[section]
\newtheorem{anmerkung}{Anmerkung}
\newtheorem{annahme}{Annahme}


\input{02_linebreak}
```

This code used to work back in 2018 (wrote my bachelor thesis using it), but now I struggle to find out what might have changed.

Any help appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: You should use `\input{01_layout}`, not `\include`.

Comment: omggggg! thanks a lot! worked!

Comment: Also is your document really saved in the non standard `ansinew` encoding? rather than `latin1` (iso-8859-1) or `utf8` (UTF-8) ?